# Removing standard CSS SLDS or overriding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, css, visual-flows

[image]I have embedded a visual flow inside a component. On embedding some of the css is not going well and the CSS class is standard on debugging I found that it is because of the class and its properties name `slds-form-element__label`
Is there any way to remove the attribute or the standard behavior of that class from your custom component. CSS is causing the below radio button break as shown in image.

I tried using

```
.THIS {
}
.THIS .slds-form-element__label {

}
```

But this doesnt worked

Comment: what is not going well can you show?

Comment: Added the image above

Comment: you want wer... in one line?

Comment: No it should use the default flow CSS .Right now its bold in text and unstructured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to override the CSS , Which was coming as default from the standard VisualFlow+Lightning community I used the component CSS markup with the css class name as the class to be overriden.

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__label {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: unset !important;
    padding: inherit !important;
}
```